# ldap_set_option() is not setting the option "LDAP_OPT_SSL"

Tags: c++, c, windows, ldap

I have a windows application that is trying to connect to ldap server running on secured port 10636.

Here's the source:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "ntldap.h"
#include "winldap.h"
#include "schnlsp.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "tchar.h"
const size_t newsize = 100;

//  Entry point for your application
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    LDAP* pLdapConnection = NULL;
    INT returnCode = 0; 
    INT connectSuccess = 0;
    ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    SecPkgContext_ConnectionInfo sslInfo;
    LONG lv = 0;

    //  Initialize an LDAP session using SSL.
    pLdapConnection = ldap_sslinit("localhost",10636,1);
    if (pLdapConnection == NULL)
    {
        printf( "ldap_sslinit failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //  Specify version 3; the default is version 2.
    printf("Setting Protocol version to 3.\n");
    returnCode = ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection,
        LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
        (void*)&version);
    if (returnCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
        goto FatalExit;

    //  Verify that SSL is enabled on the connection.
    printf("Checking if SSL is enabled\n");
    returnCode = ldap_get_option(pLdapConnection,LDAP_OPT_SSL,(void*)&lv);
    if (returnCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
        goto FatalExit;

    //  If SSL is not enabled, enable it.
    if ((void*)lv == LDAP_OPT_ON)
        printf("SSL is enabled\n");
    else
    {
        printf("SSL not enabled.\n SSL being enabled...\n");
        returnCode = ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection,LDAP_OPT_SSL,LDAP_OPT_ON);
        if (returnCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
            goto FatalExit;
    }

    //  Connect to the server.
    connectSuccess = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);

    if(connectSuccess == LDAP_SUCCESS)
        printf("ldap_connect succeeded \n");
    else
    {
        printf("ldap_connect failed with 0x%x.\n",connectSuccess);
        goto FatalExit;
    }

    //  Bind with current credentials. 
    printf("Binding ...\n");
    returnCode = ldap_bind_s(pLdapConnection,NULL,NULL,LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE);
    if (returnCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
        goto FatalExit;

    //  Retrieve the SSL cipher strength.
    printf("Getting SSL info\n");
    returnCode = ldap_get_option(pLdapConnection,LDAP_OPT_SSL_INFO,&sslInfo);
    if (returnCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
        goto FatalExit;

    printf("SSL cipher strength = %d bits\n",sslInfo.dwCipherStrength);

    goto NormalExit;

    //  Perform cleanup.
NormalExit:
    if (pLdapConnection != NULL)
        ldap_unbind_s(pLdapConnection);
    return 0;

    //  Perform cleanup after an error.
FatalExit:
    if( pLdapConnection != NULL )
        ldap_unbind_s(pLdapConnection);
    printf( "\n\nERROR: 0x%x\n", returnCode);
    return returnCode;
}
```

After setting the `ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection,LDAP_OPT_SSL,LDAP_OPT_ON);`, the application is still not able to set the option. Hence, the connection fails with return code `LDAP_SERVER_DOWN`.

Can someone point why it is not able to set the option? The server does support `ldaps://` connections.

**UPDATE:**
When I did ldapsearch on the ldap server

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://localhost -p 10636 -d 1
```

I got the error:

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://localhost:10636)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://localhost:10636/??base)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:10636
ldap_new_socket: 472
ldap_prepare_socket: 472
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying ::1 10636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 472 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect errno: 10061
ldap_close_socket: 472
ldap_new_socket: 472
ldap_prepare_socket: 472
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 127.0.0.1:10636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 472 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS trace: SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
TLS certificate verification: depth: 0, err: 18, subject: /C=US/O=ASF/OU=ApacheD
S/CN=zanzibar, issuer: /C=US/O=ASF/OU=ApacheDS/CN=zanzibar
TLS certificate verification: Error, self signed certificate
TLS trace: SSL3 alert write:fatal:unknown CA
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate B
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate B
TLS: can't connect: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:cert
ificate verify failed (self signed certificate).
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

However, after adding "TLS_REQCERT never" to ldap.conf everything started working.

Now, 
**How to make my sample program skip "TLS certificate verification"?**

Comment: Verify the server is able to accept SSL connections: 1. Use `openssl s_client -connect host:port` 2. Using a known good tool such as `ldapsearch`, attempt to connect to the server using the port specified for secure connections.

Comment: Thanks. ldapsearch as well did not work because the certificate verification failed. I am updating my post with more details

Answer (score 0):

With [`ldap_set_option`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winldap/nf-winldap-ldap_set_option) and [`LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/session-options) you can set a custome [callback-handler-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winldap/nc-winldap-verifyservercert). The result of this function determines if you want to accept/decline the specified certificate.

```cpp
static BOOLEAN IgnoreCertificateErrorsCallback (PLDAP /*pLdapConnection*/, PCCERT_CONTEXT* pServerCert) 
{
   CertFreeCertificateContext(*pServerCert);
   return true;
}

// snip
ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE, &IgnoreCertificateErrorsCallback);
```

Best advice is to put the certificate inside the windows trust-store (`certmgr.msc`) and don't disable any security feature at all.

Answer (score -2):

Try to pass the following environment variable to your code:

```
LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never
```

to ignore server certificate which could be expired or invalid.